# Eclipse plugins - safe to install?

Tags: security, eclipse, plugins

I've seen a few useful plugins for Eclipse such as [jshint-eclipse](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/). However, I'm a bit leery of installing third-party code.

Is it generally safe to install Eclipse plugins without worrying about my local system being compromised?

Comment: Generally, sure.  I've installed a bunch without problem. Though I've only ever installed the ones available through their built "install new software" system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Eclipse plug-in is basically a Java program, running inside Eclipse (and thus with the same credentials/permissions).  Running an untrusted Eclipse plug-in is approximately as safe as running an untrusted Java program.

That said, malware authors tend not to target Eclipse.

Note that I'm assuming you aren't using some sort of weird executable plug-in installer.